# Why isn't my @media working any more?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a few media queries on my CSS. They were working perfectly a few days ago but I've just noticed that none of them are doing anything. [Here they are](http://www.gradbible.com/wp-content/themes/Thoughts/style.css) in context (at the end), and this is my code:

```
    /* MOBILE OPTIMISATION */

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

    body {
        width: 89%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .post-entry {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .widgets {
        display: none;
    }

    p.frontpage_jobs {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }

    #blog-wrap {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .post-entry header h1 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

}


/* TABLET OPTIMISATION */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

body {
    width: 89%;
    //float: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.post-entry {
    width: 100%;
}

.widgets {
    display: none;
}

p.frontpage_jobs {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}

#blog-wrap {
    width: 100%;
}

.post-entry header h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

#main-content {
    width: 1200px;
}

.widgets {
    display: none;
}

}
```

**EDIT**

My site is [here](http://www.gradbible.com).

Comment: Do you have the correct meta viewport to support mobile?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm using a modified version of the Thoughts WP theme which is mobile ready (http://www.wpexplorer.com/thoughts-wordpress-theme/) and I've successfully managed to optimise for mobile before - it's somehow reverted or not applying. I presume I made another change which overrode it.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> make sure thats in your <head></head>

Comment: Yep, I have this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Comment: Which styles are not working?  Off-hand, the "only" in the first set would cause those styles to be ignored by older browsers, but I would expect styles in the sets without "only" should work.

Comment: Indeed, not enough information to go on. A link to the live site would be optimal

Comment: Updated with site link. Might a plugin be interfering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your media-queries seems to be working. Looks like you have an overflow problem. Removing "width:850px;" on .post-entry, the widths set for #main-content and the side-paddings on body as well as "width:98%;" solves the problem on the client-side for me.

That is, if it is a fluid resizing you are looking for.

Comment: Works perfectly. I'd forgotten that I'd since fiddled with the .post-entry and #main-content widths to try and fix them. Thank you!

Comment: Happy I could help. Have fun coding! :)